# Magento how to detect changed fields only in admin section?

Tags: php, magento

I need to insert some values to custom database table based on the values of changed custom field, if the specific custom field value (in a custom shipping method) had changed.I need to check this in my Observer.php event that I'm firing is `admin_system_config_changed_section_carriers` for getting values from the field and insert values to the table

is there any possible way to do this ?

**EDIT:**

here is my observer function

```
public function handle_adminSystemConfigChangedSection($observer){

        $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
        $firstBarcodeFlatrate = $post['groups']['flatrate']['fields']['barcode_start']['value'];
        $lastBarcodeFlatrate = $post['groups']['flatrate']['fields']['barcode_end']['value'];

        $flatrateRange = range($firstBarcodeFlatrate,$lastBarcodeFlatrate);
        $shippingMethod = 'flatrate';

        foreach($flatrateRange as $barcodes){
            $insertData = array(
                'barcode' => $barcodes,'shipping_method' => $shippingMethod,'status' => 1,
            );
            $model = Mage::getModel('customshippingmethods/customshippingmethods')->setData($insertData);
            try {
                $model->save();
            } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

as you can see above database query will update each time I save the configuration but I just need to run the query iff `$firstBarcodeFlatrate` value had changed

Comment: Can you please provide some of the code you are using in the observer and the values to which you have access?

Comment: @zokibtmkd I have updated my answer with Observer function I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go with two options:
1. Cache the last value of $firstBarcodeFlatrate

`$cacheId = 'first_barcode_flatrate_last_value';
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
$lastValue = $cache->load($cacheId);
if (!$lastValue) {
   //We don't have cached last value, we need to run the query and cache it:
   //Cache the value:
   $cache->save($firstBarcodeFlatrate, $cacheId, array('first_barcode_flatrate_last_value'), null);
   //Run the query here
} else {
   //We have last value, we need to check if it has been changed:
   if($lastValue != $firstBarcodeFlatrate) {
      //Update the cached value:
      $cache->save($firstBarcodeFlatrate, $cacheId, array('first_barcode_flatrate_last_value'), null);
      //Run the query here.
   }
}`

Option 2 is to create another table with a single row and two fields or add another system config field that will store the last used value. Then before the running the query, you will check this value if it's different than $firstBarcodeFlatrate you will run the query, otherwise you won't, though I think the caching will do the job for you.

Comment: I have tried first option and got it worked :) thanks . but have a confusion of the number 3600 is it the cache lifetime ? if so what happens if the admin logged after 2 days and change the value will it work ?

Comment: This is the amount of time, in seconds, that the value will exist in cache before being deleted. By setting this value to null, or omitting the argument, the value will remain in cache until removed. The answer is being edited.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation and the answer, zokibtmkd solved my problem +1

Comment: no problem, here is more about using Magento cache: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/